# How to properly configure NodeJS servers running on GCP VMs to talk to each other

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-platform, configuration

I am exploring Google Cloud Platform for hosting my solution. I have developed it locally where it works. It is part of a broader solution, but the piece where I would need some help involves an application server (VueJS/NodeJS) and a database server (NodeJS + MongoDB). When everything is local (i.e. in my machine) the connection between the web app and the database server works without issues.
The web app accesses the API (db) server via fetch. The address it accesses is localhost:4000, since the DB server was originally running on localhost:4000.

The flow is as follows: the user connects to the IP of the VM where the port 8080 is opened, gaining access to the web interface. The user then needs to login: a POST from the application server to the db server sends username and password. The DB server (REST) connects to the MongoDB instance and authenticates the user. The user is sent back to the application server.

While I can authenticate the user using a cUrl in the shell, the POST through the web page does not work. In fact I get a

> "POST http://localhost:4000/users/authenticate net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

On the db server side the request never reaches the server. Using (in a shell connected to the VM)

`curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:4000/users/authenticate' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{ "username": "username", "password": "password" }`

works properly.
The curl works also by using the internal IP of the VM.

Here are the ports for the servers and MongoDB

```
netstat -tulpn
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9128/node           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      546/mongod          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9224/node
```

I have played a little with the addresses of the servers but without obtaining any result so far. All the GCP configurations have been done via the interface rather than the cloud shell.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

In case more details are needed I am happy to provide them.